# C Linked-list Destroy Function

Tags: c, function, linked-list

I am trying to learn C, and as many people, I have been a little stuck with pointers. Anyways, I made a recursive function that destroys my linked list, but as I have debugged, when I am back from the function the head of the list is not null as it should be, so I'm guessing it's some basic misunderstanding with pointers. Here's the function:

```
void destroy(struct node *n) {
   if (!n) return;
   destroy(n->next);
   free(n);
   n = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `n` is a local variable, so `n = NULL` only has local effect -- which means it has no effect at all, since it's at the end of the function.

Comment: Please show some code which demonstrates that the head is not null.

Comment: Expanding on what @ruakh said, if you want to modify a pointer, you must pass a pointer to that pointer (i.e. a `struct node**`), just like how you would have to pass a pointer if you wanted to modify anything else.

Comment: I thought that using pointers it wouldn't have the effect of a local variable... Guess I still don't know how to implement...

Comment: @C.Porto Pointers are local variables too.

Comment: Do not use recursion. There are better ways using a loop and you will get better performance.

Answer (score 8):

```
void deleteList(struct node** head_ref)
{  
  struct node* current = *head_ref;
  struct node* next;
  while (current != NULL) {
    next = current->next;
    free(current);
    current = next;
  }
  *head_ref = NULL;
}
```

Try like this ....you can change names as you want. If you still need help let me know.

Comment: +1 for not using recurions (and thus avoiding the stackoverflow that is the inevitable consequence if the size gets large enough).

Comment: @Mats: he [plagiarized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/ive-been-accused-of-plagiarism-what-do-i-do) it from http://breakinterview.com/write-a-function-to-delete-a-linked-list/ Additional evidence, he didn't even attempt to *explain* the problem and the solution in own technical terms. This answer is clearly merely a code dump he luckily found on Google along with a doubting "try this ...".

Comment: @BalusC head_ref is a starting of the list ...then next pointer points to the next of current ,afterwords space is freed pointed by current and current points to next and next points to next address of that current.
while keeps on checking if it is not null...;)
I did not get lucky, I know what I wrote man...else I wouldn't have written it,FYI it is not using recursion which is obvious that's y liked a comment of Ed Heal

Comment: Would this code be any different if `struct node* next;` was changed into `struct node* next = current->next;` and replaced the first line of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 4):

Head has been freed when this functions ends but it's not null. Everything in C is passed by value. So you pass a copy of the location of head into destroy. That memory is deallocated but head is not changed.

You could write this as:

```
destroy(&head);

void destroy(struct node** n){
   if(!*n) return;
   destroy(&((*n)->next));
   free(*n);
   *n = NULL; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a pointer pointing to your list, calling with `destroy(&n)`:

```
// clear complete list 
void destroy(struct node **n)
{
    if (*n == NULL)
        return;

    if ((*n)->next == NULL)
    {
        free(*n);
        *n= NULL;
        return;
    }

    struct node *iter = *n;
    struct node *prev = NULL;

    // get last item and the previous one
    while (iter->next != NULL)
    {
        prev = iter;
        iter = iter -> next;
    } 

    prev->next = NULL;
    free(iter);

    destroy(n);
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Your call to `clear()` is unclear; did you mean to call `destroy()` again?  Your loop to find the end before releasing something, then calling the function again recursively (with simple tail recursion at that) seems a little odd;.  I think it will work (I've not tested it), but the original code with recursion and no loop is simpler — though it might recurse more deeply than your code does.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Indeed it should be `destroy()`. And yes, my function is a bit too circuitous and I will take a look at the other solutions posted here to improve my one. However, it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive `destroy` function cannot modify the `head` variable in the caller's frame.

The statement `n = NULL` only affects the function argument, which is a local variable of the `destroy` function. It actually has no effect, so you can remove this statement.

You should set the `head` to `NULL` after the call to `destroy` in the caller function if it is needed there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample function to destroy Linked list using `DeleteRear()`:

```
void Destroy_Using_Rear(List *L)
{
    int y;
    Node *P,*Q,*Z;

    while(P!=NULL){
        y=DeleteRear(L,x);
        return y;
        Z=P;
        P=*L;
    }
}
```