# how to destroy a linked list in c?

Tags: c

i have this node :

```
typedef struct node {
    DATA *dataa ;
    struct node* next;
} *node_v;
```

with the asumption that i have already filled the linked list .. i want now to go over it and destroy it ..
i have made this function to destroy :

```
void destroyList(Node ptr) {
    while(ptr) {
        Node toDelete = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free(toDelete);
    }
}
```

it takes a node and free it . but my problem that each node i made the next points to NULL and the previous node points to the new node !
but the destroylist function does the opposite.. which means in order to deleate a node i call the function destroy list with the the last node i entered but then the toDeleate also points to it and the last node i enetred now points to the next node which in my case it is null , so i want to do the opposite.. any ideas of hiw i can do this !
like how can i make a destroy function that goes in the opposite direction !?

Comment: Your destroy function is *correct*. However, there seems to be something missing from your *building* function. Because to have a linked list, you have to keep pointer to the node that points to the rest and you apparently don't. But since you didn't include that code, we can't point out the exact mistake to you.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412620/c-linked-list-destroy-function)

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but you should indent your code.

Comment: `void destroyList(Node ptr) ...` Node is not a typedeffed name. (are you using C++, BTW ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I call the function destroy list with the the last node I entered ... how can I make a destroy function that goes in the opposite direction?

With a singly-linked list, there is only one direction you *can* go, the direction in which the links are pointing. It *sounds* like the state of your list after building is something like:

```
                          pointer
                             |
                             V
firstVal -> secondVal -> thirdVal -> NULL
```

and you then call `destroyList(pointer)`. That is *not* what you need for a singly-linked list. Such a list should maintain a head pointer to the *start* of the list, as follows:

```
 pointer
    |
    V
firstVal -> secondVal -> thirdVal -> NULL
```

If you were to build your list like that, then your code for destroying the list would work just fine.

Since you haven't actually *shown* the code that builds the list (instead giving only a description of said list once built), that's most likely your problem.

In order to build the list correctly, you can use pseudo-code such as:

```
head = null
def append(head, tail, node):
    node.next = null
    if head == null:
        head = node
        tail = node
        return
    tail.next = node
    tail = node
```

Comment: @iBug: if you avoid list comprehensions and the like, Python is the *perfect* pseudo-code language because (1) it's easy to understand and (2) it's testable :-)